# could not find property 'sourceSets' on root project gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying run gradle task. Before running one task I want to see all available tasks `gradle tasks`. To do it I go to the directory of my project, where is file `build.gradle`. When I have executed command I got an error

> could not find property 'sourceSets' on root project gradle

Comment: Have you applied java plugin, with `apply plugin: 'java'`?

Comment: @Opal yes, there is 
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "findbugs"

Comment: Also, `sourcesets` is case-sensitive. Should be `sourceSets` everywhere.

Comment: @ Opal It is also case-sensitive, as I added in question

Comment: Gradle message you pasted is all lowercase.

Comment: @Opal It is just my error, because I didn't paste this message from command line, just type

Comment: @Opal Have you any other ideas in which thing can be an error?

Comment: Ok, share you `build.gradle` that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Opal I have added

Answer (score 7):

Plugins that are applied to `build.gradle` should be at the very beginning of the `build.gradle` script. Move:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
```

to the beginning of the script.

Comment: 'java' and 'findbugs' need to be with double quotes or no?

Comment: @Viktoriia, it's groovy - doesn't matter in this particular case.

Comment: @Viktoriia, use `ext.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'`, however this is another question.

Comment: Now `Could not find property 'war' `

Comment: @Viktoriia, no. You need to apply another plugin: `apply plugin: 'war'`.

Comment: I done it and then `Could not find property publish' `

Comment: @Viktoriia, try `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`.

Comment: done it and then 'Could not find property 'release'`

Comment: @Viktoriia, no idea where  does `release` task may come from. Probably from a custom plugin. Please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: @Viktoriia, try to replace `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'` with `apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'`.

Comment: @Viktoriia, my nick is _Opal_, not _Oral_. No idea, as I said where does `release`  task can come from. Where did you take this `build.gradle` file?

Comment: sorry for nick), I have written tests on this project and now need to run them on TeamCity. I download this project grom git. So I need create gradle task and run it

Comment: @Viktoriia, you downloaded a `build.gradle` without plugins applied? Check once again.

Comment: There were only 
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

Comment: @Viktoriia, show where did you take it from, please.

Comment: @Viktoriia, I cannot help you then.